# Crashlytics sendUnsentReports() doesn't work even with FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(false)

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, crashlytics

I need to send my reports right after the errors happens, but Crashlytics only send them when i restart the app.

I tried to follow the documentation and implement this in different ways, but everytime it seems to lead to the same outcome, which is that Crashlytics only send the reports after i restart the app. I get that this is the expected behavior, but it is completely useless for my app's purposes.

---

main.dart

```
    ...
    FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(false);
    ...
```

---

AndroidManifest.xml

```
...
    <meta-data
            android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled"
            android:value="false" />
...
```

---

firebase_util.dart

```
...
      await FirebaseCrashlytics.instance
          .recordError(error, stackTrace, printDetails: true)
          .then((value) async => await FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.sendUnsentReports());
...
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The Android SDK will try to send the crash report after it happens, if you are on the latest Crashlytics SDK version this should be the case.

But in iOS, unfortunately, this will happen only after restarting the app. As far as I know, this is to avoid issues where the app gets closed while making network requests.

In relation to setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(false), this is intended for giving users more control of their data. You would set this to false in the manifest (for [Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?platform=android#enable-reporting)) or in the Info.plist ([for iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?platform=ios#enable-reporting)) to prevent Crashlytics from sending crash data. This explains why crashes not were being sent when calling:

```
FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.sendUnsentReports()
```

Then you could ask the user for their consent and if they do, you can set this value to true with:

```
FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true)
```

After doing this, Crashlytics will start collecting and sending crash reports. But it will follow the process from above.